# Could not get resource

Tags: java, android, gradle

After updating android studio to 3.1 my projects are not compiling.
While syncing with Gradle showing error.

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I am not getting any way to create a certificate and add in the trust store.

Comment: full error logs

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: I create certificate and added but still having same problem.
On same machine android studio 2.3 is working but i created my next project in kotlin so android studio 3.0/3.1 is required 

exact error coming while going to download POM file.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.0/gradle-3.1.0.pom'.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.0/gradle-3.1.0.pom'

Comment: Even i tried [link] (http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target) too. but no luck.
Please help someone i am stuck here for almost a week.

Comment: I tried with multiple java versions and android studio 3.0, 3.1, 3,2-canary but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got a solution, the error was in K7 Antivirus. somehow K7 blocking all API calls from 3.0 and above.
As I uninstalled K7 I am good to go.